# Pagination for SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Hey Friends I am working on a application which I similar to service now. I have requests coming from users and have to work on it. I am using python-flask and sqlite for this.

I am new to flask and this is my first project. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT * from orders")
orders = result.fetchmany(5)
```

I am trying to use `orders = result.paginate(...)`

But it seems there's some problem. 
Also, I am not sure of how to display the db data in different pages.

I want first 10 records on 1st page next 10 on 2nd page and so on..

Could you please help me?

Comment: This is not so easy. You need the backend and frontend to work together. I suggest looking at the [Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination)

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results is a good introduction to the SQL side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used flask but assuming that you can issue a paginate/page throw then a query that introduces a value 0-9 would allow a conditional page throw.

For example, assuming an **orders** tables that has 3 columns, **orderdate**, **ordertype**, **orderdesc** and that the order required was for the columns according to those columns (see notes) then the following would inroduce a column that is from 0 to 9 and thus allow the check for a pafe throw :-

```
SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT count() 
        FROM ORDERS 
        WHERE orderdate||ordertype||orderdesc < o.orderdate||o.ordertype||o.orderdesc 
        ORDER BY orderdate||ordertype||orderdesc
    ) % 10 AS orderby

FROM ORDERS AS o ORDER BY orderdate||ordertype||orderdesc
```

- Note that the above relies upon sort-orders and the where clause having the same result, a more complex WHERE clause may be needed. The above is intended as an in-principle example.

## Example Usage

Consider the following example of the above in use. This generates 100 rows of orders with randomly generated orderdates and ordertypes within specififc ranges and then extracts the data according to the above query. The results of the underyling data and the extracted data are shown in the results section.

```
/* Create Test Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
/* Generate and load some random orders */
CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS orders (orderdate TEXT, ordertype TEXT, orderdesc TEXT);
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(od,ot,counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            datetime('now','+'||(abs(random()) % 10)||' days'),
            (abs(random()) % 26),
            1
        UNION ALL SELECT 
            datetime('now','+'||(abs(random()) % 10)||' days'),
            (abs(random()) % 26),
            counter+1  
        FROM cte1 LIMIT 100
    )
INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM cte1;

/* Display the resultant data */
SELECT rowid,* FROM orders;

/* Display data with generated page throw indicator */
SELECT rowid,*,
    (
        SELECT count() 
        FROM ORDERS 
        WHERE orderdate||ordertype||orderdesc < o.orderdate||o.ordertype||o.orderdesc 
        ORDER BY orderdate||ordertype||orderdesc
    ) % 10 AS orderby
FROM ORDERS AS o ORDER BY orderdate||ordertype||orderdesc;
/* Clean up */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
```

## Results (partial)

### The core data (not sorted so by rowid (rowid included for comparison purposes)) :-

[image]

### The extracted data with page-throw indicator (highlighted)

[image]

- Obviously you would likely not throw a page for the first row.
- As concatention of the 3 columns has been used for convenience, the results may be a little confusing as e.g. 2 would appear to be greater than 11 and so on.
- the rowid indicates the original position, so demonstrates that the data has been sorted.

Comment: Thank for such a detailed explanation. This helped me a lot to understand

Comment: @shubhammetha that's good, if the asnwer helped you then please tick it as answered.